# Why Android support java but not other languages?

Tags: java, android, operating-system

I see the statement below on Google in one form or another

> Most of the Android development is Java based because Android supports
>   a large number of Java libraries

I am coming from Java based web application background. I have never heard the statement "Windows supports one specific language but Linux does not". Then why in context of mobile OS we say android supports Java. The role of any OS is to execute the commands and not to support the specific language, right?

I know I am missing something basic here, but what's that?

Comment: more like android and java are extremely close cousins, and android is BASED on java.

Comment: OS doesn't execute any language program totally by itself. It needs compiler/interpreter/linker. Try adding a C# compiler in Android OS!

Comment: BTW you can use NDK and code in C++ or use Xamarin and code in C#.

Comment: @MarcB again my question is same. Android is os but java is programming language. So are we not comparing apple with orange here  ? My question is why noid android support like all languages C,C++ like windows, linux  ?

Comment: android isn't just java. android-the-os actually uses the linux kernel. so anything you can compile for a linux kernel can theoreatically "run" in android. and you CAN use other languages to build for android. there are native c++ apps and whatnot. it's just EASIER to use "java".

Comment: Of course, any OS can support any language that has compilers, interpreters, linkers, and runtimes available to it. But the key here is "available to it". Google consciously chose Java as the primary development language of Android, and as a result, built a runtime for it with Java support. They could've chosen to support any other language, but they didn't. The statement "Android supports Java" means that if you can get F# or Brainfuck apps to work on Android, good for you. If you run into problems with the resulting apps though, the blame won't be on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then why in context of mobile OS we say android support java.

I do not know who "we" is. Experienced computer programmers would not say that, and even your made-up quote does not say that.

> Role of any OS is to execute the commands not to support the specific language right ?

Correct. And, given a rooted Android device, you are welcome to try porting any language you like to Android, and in a custom ROM mod, you are welcome to arrange to allow the user to run any program they want in any of those supported languages.

However, most people do not have rooted Android devices.
On a normal Android device, the Android frameworks put some limitations on what you easily can use for programming.

For example, you can divide the world of Java-capable servers into two main categories:

- Those where you have complete control over the server, which is roughly equivalent to running a rooted Android device
- Those where all you can do is upload a WAR and related files (e.g., static assets), which are run on a Java-powered server managed by somebody else

In that latter scenario, you are not going to have complete flexibility in programming. Presumably, you could integrate JVM-based scripting languages, but you may have difficulty in using C++. That is not an issue with the OS — the server itself is probably perfectly capable of running a C++ program. It is an issue of the framework in which your code is running (whatever people use for WARs nowadays, as it has been a long time since I worked in server-side Java development).

The primary framework for Android development is based on Java. Courtesy of `WebView`, this also opens up hooks for hybrid development (HTML/CSS/JS). `NativeActivity` makes it possible to write full Android apps in C/C++. Various toolchains allow you to write in other languages (e.g., Kotlin) that compile into something that works with Android's frameworks, and you can embed scripting languages. But you still need to stick to the frameworks, which puts some limits on what you can do and how you can do it. This is not the fault of the Android OS, but rather the frameworks.

Comment: when you say `That is not an issue with the OS — the server itself is probably perfectly capable of running a C++ program. It is an issue of the framework in which your code is running` i believe framework here means jvm for java where jvm instructions are well interpreted by os like android,windows,Linux. But similarly there is environment for C++ whose instructions are not interpreted correctly by normal android device (though can be interpreted by rooted android). Is that you mean here ?

Comment: @emilly: "i believe framework here means jvm for java" -- no. In that context, I am referring to your WAR container (Tomcat? Jetty? whatever people use for that nowadays).

Comment: ok then you mean application/war container(like tomcat ) instructions are well interpreted by os like android,windows,Linux. But similarly there is environment for C++ whose instructions are not interpreted correctly by normal android device (though can be interpreted by rooted android). Is that you mean here ?

Comment: @emilly: No. I mean that a WAR cannot be written in arbitrary programming languages. It has to be something that the framework (WAR container) supports. The WAR container is not the operating system. Similarly, the Android app framework is not the operating system, and you will be limited to programming languages that can work with the app framework, for deployment to conventional Android devices.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Android is based on Java. But recently the grandpa Delphi acquired fire monkey, which is supposed to transform Delphi code in to native Android code. That way it supposedly run just like a native application.